# pgadmin4 container with kerberos

Tags: kerberos, pgadmin-4, enterprisedb

I'm trying to use the pgadmin4 container image with kerberos, according to https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/kerberos.html.

The pgadmin webinterface keeps telling me "Delegated credentials not supplied." But the Authorization header is transmitted properly. What am I doing wrong`?

Here is a curl dump:

**Command line:**

```sh
kinit myuser
curl  -v --negotiate --user : http://***MYHOST***/login
```

**Output**:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 172.28.28.133:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to ***MYHOST*** (172.28.28.133) port 80 (#0)
* Server auth using Negotiate with user ''
> GET /login HTTP/1.1
> Host: ***MYHOST***
> Authorization: Negotiate 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
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: gunicorn
< Date: Tue, 07 Sep 2021 15:24:47 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 6073
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Content-Security-Policy: default-src ws: http: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Set-Cookie: pga4_session=f372e462-19be-4c4b-926f-d23469d51237!ckfFYMTygG5gvVXmXlhZglyHop4=; Expires=Wed, 08-Sep-2021 15:24:47 GMT; HttpOnly; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
< 
{ [6073 bytes data]
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title>pgAdmin 4</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- To set pgAdmin4 shortcut icon in browser -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico?ver=50600"/>

    <!-- Base template stylesheets -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/js/generated/style.css?ver=50600"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/js/generated/pgadmin.style.css?ver=50600"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/js/generated/pgadmin.css?ver=50600"/>

     <!--View specified stylesheets-->
    
    <script type="application/javascript">
        /* This is used to change publicPath of webpack at runtime */
        window.resourceBasePath = "/static/js/generated/";
    </script>
    <!-- Base template scripts -->
    <script type="application/javascript"
            src="/static/vendor/require/require.min.js?ver=50600"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript">
            require.config({
                baseUrl: '',
                urlArgs: 'ver=50600',
                waitSeconds: 0,
                shim: {},
                paths: {
                    sources: "/static/js",
                    datagrid: "/static/js/generated/datagrid",
                    sqleditor: "/static/js/generated/sqleditor",
                    'pgadmin.browser.utils': "/browser/" + "js/utils",
                    'pgadmin.browser.endpoints': "/browser/" + "js/endpoints",
                    'pgadmin.browser.messages': "/browser/" + "js/messages",
                    'pgadmin.browser.constants': "/browser/" + "js/constants",
                    'pgadmin.server.supported_servers': "/browser/" + "server/supported_servers",
                    'pgadmin.user_management.current_user': "/user_management/" + "current_user",
                    'translations': "/tools/" + "translations"
                }
            });

    </script>

    <!-- View specified scripts -->
    <script type="application/javascript" src="/static/js/generated/vendor.main.js?ver=50600" ></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="/static/js/generated/vendor.others.js?ver=50600" ></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="/static/js/generated/pgadmin_commons.js?ver=50600" ></script>

</head>
<body>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade
    your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
<![endif]-->

<div class="container-fluid h-100 login_page">
        <div style="position: fixed; top: 20px; right: 20px; width: 400px; z-index: 9999">
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        Delegated credentials not supplied.
        <button onclick="hide()" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span
                aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    </div>
    </div>
<script>
function hide(){
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    if (target.type === undefined)
        target=target.parentNode;
    target.parentNode.classList.remove("show");
}
</script>
    <div class="row h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-6"><div class="pr-4">
 <img src="/static/img/login.svg?ver=50600" alt="Login">
</div>
</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="panel-header text-color h4"><i class="app-icon pg-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i> pgAdmin 4</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="d-block text-color pb-3 h5">Login</div>
                <form action="/authenticate/login" method=
100  6073  100  6073    0     0   197k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  197k
* Connection #0 to host ***MYHOST*** left intact
"POST" name="login_user_form">
    <input id="next" name="next" type="hidden" value="">
<input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="ImY4Y2U0NDVmOTZhYmNiYWM2MjU1Njk2YWUxNGU2ZTM2NjlmODgxODQi.YTeEPw.goqhnkaxNASl3A7wzXHiKeqEWis">
        <div class="form-group mb-3 ">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address / Username" name="email"
           type="text" autofocus>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group mb-3 ">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password"
           type="password" autofocus>
    </div>

    <button name="internal_button"  disabled  class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-login" type="submit" value="Login">Login</button>
    <div class="form-group row mb-3 c user-language">
        <div class="col-7"><span class="help-block"><a href="/browser/reset_password" class="text-white">Forgotten your password</a>?</span></div>
        <div class="col-5">
            <select class="form-control" name="language" value="en">
                                <option value="en" selected>English</option>
                                <option value="zh" >Chinese (Simplified)</option>
                                <option value="cs" >Czech</option>
                                <option value="fr" >French</option>
                                <option value="de" >German</option>
                                <option value="it" >Italian</option>
                                <option value="ja" >Japanese</option>
                                <option value="ko" >Korean</option>
                                <option value="pl" >Polish</option>
                                <option value="ru" >Russian</option>
                                <option value="es" >Spanish</option>
                            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="application/javascript">
            
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**
Please understand that I have hidden host, user and realm to disguise my employer.

Further details from inside the container:

```
/pgadmin4 # klist -k -t /etc/krb5.keytab
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Timestamp         Principal
---- ----------------- --------------------------------------------------------
   3 01/01/70 00:00:00 HTTP/***MYHOST***@***MYREALM***

/pgadmin4 # kinit ***MYUSER***
Password for ***MYUSER***@***MYREALM***: ***
/pgadmin4 #
```

... so I concluded my keytab is correct, my kerberos configuration works (due to the fact that kinit works) (?)

By the way, I am using the same keytab with the same serviceprincipalname on the same host with a webserver container that works - so I do not suspect problems with the serviceprincipalname in general(?)

Comment: what are the settings of your SPN account? Is the delegation enabled on it?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Please see my EDIT. --- Concerning delegation: I do not have access to the ActiveDirectory, but I can tell you the stuff works with the same serviceprincipalname on the same host with another webserver container, as described in my EDIT.

Comment: The error mentions "Delegated credentials not provided" - basically your app is trying to acquire kerb ticket for Service B from the ticket it received from the browser(note the ticket browser sends is for your service).  Server fails to obtain that second ticket based on the ticket it received. This happens due to bad configuration at KDC level - especially when your service principal is not allowed to delegate the credentials.

Comment: Are you using windows kdc? if yes, you can check the user attributes of your service principal (keytab principal) inside AD - check if the delegation is enabled for the appropriate service

Comment: Is it possible that delegation was not neccessary for my other webservice that works, but is neccessary for pgadmin4? Why? Does pgadmin try the so-called "second phase" as described in https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/kerberos-support-pgadmin-4 ? Documentation is sparse. - I will try to reach my AD admin to enable delegation.

Comment: the above link mentions future versions will have delegation to postgres. But I believe it is expecting delegated credentials internally - not sure of they have part of it already coded in their current release. Your IT Admin should help you in this.